# Visual studio Form runs in old theme

Tags: visual-studio

I am very new to visual studio. I have designed some windows form in visual studio (vb). The form looks like this:
[image]

However, when I run the code (press Start debugging button), it runs in old-styled theme as shown below:

[image]

The designed color scheme and running scheme are not same. I tried to clean and rebuild everything, but it did not solve the issue. a help would be really appreciable. Thanks :)

Comment: this is visual studio, not vs code

Comment: the GUI builder generates some C# code, look at these files to see what the code is that is run